# How to install ubuntu 15.04 with windows 8.1 in dual boot menu

Tags: windows-8

I firstly installed windows 8.1 and after ubuntu 15.04. The problem is that when the computer boots, it only runs ubuntu. I want a dual boot menu for both OS. How can fix the problem?

Other question: when I install ubuntu 15.04 it doesn't let me choose the option: "install ubuntu with windows 8.1". What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your GRUB may be messed up. Try inserting the Ubuntu install CD, and click "Try Ubuntu."

When the desktop loads up, open terminal, and install Boot-repair using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Click the recommended repair button after the Boot repair window comes up, and then wait for it to load. What this does, is reinstalls your GRUB bootloader, and fixes any problems it may have as well. Hope I helped!